# CakePHP 2.4.5 and CakePHP 4.x database sharing

Tags: php, cakephp

I've inherited this old CakePHP 2.4.5 webapp that works ok. My customer asks me to develop new features for it. I know it's going to be a mess, but the features my customer wants do not need to write to the existing database tables, only read them. New data will be stored in new tables that the current (old) webapp will never see.

Moreover new features are almost unrelated to the existing ones, except for users authentication. Users can be asked to use a different login page to access the new features, but theiy can't be asked to sign up again and to have different user accounts. New users will keep signing up using the old webapp.

I know almost nothing of CakePHP, be it the old 2.4.5 release or the current 4.0.6. I do know and develop in PHP in general though.

Is it possible and safe (in terms of data integrity) to configure a new CakePHP 4.0.6 webapp with two database connections, where the first one is the old webapp database, shared only to keep authentication working and as read-only reference, and the second one is for new features and new data?

Will CakePHP 4.0.6 automatically update anything in the shared database? Will it work at all?

Comment: To be clear, do you need to have two separate databases, or can it be two applications accessing different tables in the same database?

Comment: No need to have two databases, I just mentioned that because it seemed to me a cleaner way to go, but I can just make different tables in the same database if that helps

Comment: If it's all in the same database, then it's really pretty trivial. Just configure the new application so that it reads from and writes to the same database as the old one. Access only the tables you need to. If you set up cookies correctly, you should be able to easily get single sign on. You can even run them from the same URL structure with some rewriting adjustments.

Comment: To be clear, do you mean CakePHP 4 won't update anything in the `users` table and it will work out of the box with the users table of CakePHP version 2.4.5?

Comment: It should. Apart from the sessions table I don't think there's any tables that Cake updates without you writing code to update. And the authentication system is highly configurable, so it's pretty much a guarantee that if it doesn't quite work with the existing users table, it would be a pretty minor configuration matter to get it going.